# get_edit_tag_link does not return anything

Tags: tags

I'm trying to pull up a custom page which lists all tags used in my blog that have a description, to build up a glossary.

It all works great but i would also like to display an "edit tag" link for each tag, only visible to admins. The built-in [edit_tag_link() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/edit_tag_link) is supposed to do just that, as far as i understand the codex, but the edit link does not show up. What is wrong with my code?

```
$tags = get_tags();
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    if(strlen($tag->description)>0){
            $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
            print_r($tag);
    echo "<li><a class='content-link' href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'><h3>{$tag->name}</h3>
    <pclass='abstract'>{$tag->description}</p></a> ".edit_tag_link('edit tag','<p>','</p>',$tag)."</li>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the edit_term_link() function works fine for that.

```
        edit_term_link('edit tag','<p>','</p>',$tag);
```